# Which philosophers provide theories of subjectivity?

Tags: reference-request, history-of-philosophy, subjectivity

Which philosophers write about subjectivity? What are some primary sources for philosophical theories of subjectivity?

Comment: Also: Georges Rey, Dan Dennett, Peter Carruthers.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this comes under the general heading of "philosophy of mind."

The first two contemporary philosophers I can think of who write, specifically, about the nature of subjectivity:

[Thomas Nagel](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Thomas_Nagel), author of the essay, [What is it like to be a bat](http://organizations.utep.edu/Portals/1475/nagel_bat.pdf)?

[Thomas Metzinger](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Thomas_Metzinger), author of [The Ego Tunnel](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0465045677).

Answer (score 3):

**For a general overview of this very interesting subtopic in philsophy of mind:**
*What is it like to be a bat?* by **Thomas Nagel**
*Could love be like a heatwave?* by **Janet Levin**
*Knowing one's own mind* by **Donald Davidson**
*Individualism and self-knowledge* by **Tyler Burge**
*Anti-individualism and privileged access* by **Michael McKinsey**

**For further reading, you might considering checking out some of these as recommended by [my philosophy of mind anthology](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0199253838):**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what one means by "subjectivity", the answer is "pretty much all of them."

The question is so broad as to make an intelligent answer difficult.

That being said: if we want to point out a few of the more radical views, Nietzsche's dictum that there are no facts, only interpretations is certainly a noteworthy milestone, as is [Wittgenstein's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophical_Investigations#Wittgenstein.27s_beetle) [beetle](http://www.philosophyonline.co.uk/pom/pom_behaviourism_wittgenstein.htm)[-box](http://virtualphilosopher.com/2006/09/wittgenstein_an.html) thought experiment.